# 3D Pie Chart using Highcharter

Tags: r, highcharts, 3d

I'm trying to plot a 3D pie chart using highcharter library, but can't manage the category labels to show up. A reproducible  code is given below:

```r
data <- data.frame(
  category = c("A", "B", "C"),
  value = c(10, 20, 30)
)

highchart() %>% 
  hc_chart(type ="pie",
           options3d = list(enabled = TRUE, beta = 0, alpha = 60)) %>%
  hc_xAxis(categories = data$category) %>%
  hc_add_series(data = data$value, name = "Value") %>% 
  hc_plotOptions(pie = list(depth = 70))
```

The plot looks like this:
[3D Pie Chart using highcharter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLFme.png)

This same approach works with bar plots, but not with pies. Can anyone help me with this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This way will helps

```
hchart(dummy, type = "pie", hcaes(category, value)) %>%
  hc_chart(options3d = list(enabled = TRUE, beta = 0, alpha = 60)) %>%
  hc_xAxis(categories = data$category) %>%
  hc_plotOptions(pie = list(depth = 70))
```

[image: Pie]

Comment: it worked. thanks a lot!